# Avoid repetition in SQL Query

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables.

**Project**

```
Project ID | Project Name
         1 | Project 1
         2 | Project 2
```

**Enhancement Pjt**

```
Enh ID | Enh Name   | Project ID
    1  | Enh Name 1 | 1
    2  | Enh Name 2 | 1
    3  | Enh Name 3 | 2
```

**Support Table**

```
Supp. ID | Supp. Proj Name | Project ID
       1 | Supp Name 1     | 1
       2 | Supp Name 2     | 2
       3 | Supp Name 3     | 2
```

I want to create a query table which lists all the Projects and their associated Enh. Projects and Support Projects. I used joins but the result contains repeating columns in the support table which is quite confusing for a report.

Comment: Can you post the query you have started creating? It could be a helpful place to start.

Comment: Also, please provide the desired output for this input.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see which database server (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc...) you're using.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use `union all`. This could be a start:

```
select 
  'Enhancement: ' type_,
   p.name,
   e.name
from 
   project p,
   enhancement e
where
   p.id = 
   e.project_id
      UNION ALL
select 
  'Support: ' type_,
   p.name,
   s.name
from 
   project p,
   support s
where
   p.id = 
   s.project_id;
```

**Background for my proposal:**

I believe what the original posters wants to avoid is the following repetition

```
select
  p.name,
  e.name,
  s.name
from
  project     p,
  enhancement e,
  support     s
where
  p.id = e.project_id and
  p.id = s.project_id ;
```

results in

```
NAME            NAME            NAME
--------------- --------------- ---------------
Project one     Enhancement 2   Support 1
Project one     Enhancement 1   Support 1
Project two     Enhancement 3   Support 2
Project two     Enhancement 3   Support 3
```

That is: *Enhancement 3* and *Support 1* is returned twice, which is (probably) not wanted.

However, with my proposal, the query returns

```
TYPE_         NAME            NAME
------------- --------------- ---------------
enhancement:  Project one     Enhancement 1
enhancement:  Project one     Enhancement 2
enhancement:  Project two     Enhancement 3
support:      Project one     Support 1
support:      Project two     Support 2
support:      Project two     Support 3
```

that is, each enhancement and support case is returned exactly once.

I have chosen `UNION ALL` instead `UNION` so that the RDBMS does not have to do the extra step of filtering out duplicate records (which I believe is not necessary).

Comment: Note the title is "Avoid repetition" and that `UNION ALL` is designed to **allow** duplicate rows.

Comment: You're right what `union all` concerns, but I have interpreted the poster's question as how to avoid the repetition of enhancements and projects in an ordinary (that is something like `select ... from project, enhancement, support ... where project.id = enhancment.project_id and project.id = support.project_id`)

Comment: Suggest you change `UNION ALL` to `UNION` to avoid confusion (I'm almost tempted to say `UNION CORRESPONDING` ;)

Comment: I have edited the answer to make the choosing for `UNION ALL` more clear.

Comment: Fair enough but it isn't required: the presence of differing literals for `type_` makes it dead easy for the optimizer to realize that filtering out duplicate rows is not necessary but perhaps the same cannot be said of the human reader. +1 regardless of our differing opinions :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for aliases

try something like this:

```
select p.name as project_name1, // the 'as' might be superfluous ... not sure right now
       e.name as enhancement_name1
from project as p, enhancement as e // whataver the desired jon condition is
where p.id = e.project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

andIt would help if you could explain the relationships of your tables. It appears to me as though each Project *may* have a related Enhancement Project and/or a related Support Project. If I am understanding you correctly then the below will work.

```
    SELECT
    p.ProjectID,
    p.ProjectName,
    e.EnhName,
    s.SuppProjName
    FROM
    Project p 
    LEFT JOIN EnhanchementPJT e ON p.ProjectID = e.ProjectID
    LEFT JOIN SupportTable s ON p.ProjectID = s.ProjectID
```